# Is there a diff tool for seeing what content has changed in a text field?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow

When content changes happen to a text field, i want to list the words/sentences that have changed. A bit like how track changes work in Microsoft Word or Google Docs. Or like how Git does a diff in a file.

For example, we have a description field: "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy cow"

And then someone goes and makes a change to this field to: "the fast blue whale jumps over the lazy cow".

I want to capture the change of the words/sentences within the field. Please note this will generally have lots of phrases/sentences in the field

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you looked at the standard [Field History Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tracking_field_history.htm&type=5) feature?

Comment: @DavidCheng i need to get what has changed so i can email it across to a team. I dont think field history tracking would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't anything out of the box that provides the level of functionality. In the past I've implemented The [jsdiff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff) library to provide this functionality in a custom component.

The past implementation that I used this for was for authoring Knowledge Articles however, which meant that we had built in versioning of all of the content and this was just a visual indicator to help with the review process. If you're tracking changes to long text fields you'd need to save each version of the text as you won't be able to retrieve this information from the field history records.